# How to parse -<postive number>

Tags: bash

I have a bash interface to using command `-n <postive int>` to assgin `var`.
Could I refactor it to assign `var` with command `-<postive integer>` by bash?

```
# original code
while (("$#")); do
  case "$1" in
    -n)
      [ "$2" -gt 0 ] 2>/dev/null || exit 1
      var=$2
      shift 2

# Omit the below
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash [interprets the `case` tests](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testbranch.html). That means, you can do this:

```sh
case "${1/-/}" in
    *[!0-9]*|"")
        # handle any non-integer parameters
        ;;
    *)
      var="${1/-/}"
      shift
      ;;
esac
```

(`${//}` syntax [explainer](https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/pattern-substitution/). In a nutshell: strips off the first dash.)